# Is there a way to for a site builder to make sure context-teaser is used in "Teaser" mode when an atom is in rich text?

Tags: wysiwyg, nodes, scald

In **Scald**, when an atom reference field is inserted into a node, the site builder can specify the context per view mode (i.e. the "Full page" context as "default" and a "Teaser" context for the "teaser" view mode). So far, so good.

However, when not using atom reference fields, but instead using WYSIWYG where the author "drag'n'drop" the atom into rich text, the context and alignment are chosen by the author. E.g. the author may pick `context-full` and `atom-align-center`. These choices are made part of the SAS and in appears various places in the render array for the body/node.  If you inspect the render array, you find that the SAS may look like this (where "XXXX" is the atom's sid):

```
<div class="dnd-atom-wrapper type-image context-full atom-align-center" contenteditable="false">
<div class="dnd-drop-wrapper">[scald=XXXX:full {"link":""}]</div>
```

Now, I think it is just fine that **Scald** empowers the author to set the context and alignement for the *default* view mode for the atom.

However, out of the box, the default context set by the author is used in *all* view modes, *including* "teaser".  I have not yet found a simple way for the site builder to indicate that a *different* context (e.g. `context-teaser`) and alignment (e.g. `atom-align-right`) shall be used in the "teaser" view mode.

I have been able to think of some workarounds:

1. the author is required to create a "Summary" by hand and to select the "teaser" context for the summary.
2. A preprocess function is set up to rewrite the SAS to use `context-teaser`, etc. *if* the view_mode is "teaser".
3. Don't use WYSIWYG for atoms (instead, use a unlimited field to hold Atom references).

However, I don't like these workarounds.  I don't want to burden the author with creating a summary for every node. Such a massive rewrites of the render array is hackish and fragile. Not having atoms is WYSIWYG is just not acceptable for some of my users.  The way I see it, these workarounds is not really usable.

Can anyone think of a *usable* way to for site builders using **Scald** for media management to control the context of all *aggregate* renderings of nodes, while still having context and alignment under the author's control (i.e. in WYSIWYG)  for the full page view mode?